# How to handle huge form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a question, how do you handle a huge data from forms with php and mysql?

I have the next:
~ 50 fields (input text, checkboxex, select, textarea)

After that, I need to save this into MySQL database, and I need to select and filter this data. 
Do you have a practice, and what do you use in your projects?

Comment: Is there a specific question? There is no native inhibitor preventing you from submitting 50 fields (certainly over POST - with GET you can eventually run into URL length limits).

Comment: [here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411811/how-to-post-a-form-with-many-fields-with-jquery) assuming that your `huge` equals  `many fields` and not `large fields`

Comment: I mean maybe there frameworks or methods, that can help me. I very tired to handle via $_POST['field'] - > insert into database.

Comment: **bart s** thanks, I forgot about jQuery =)

Comment: The question is about how should he handle the database, how would heh andle the code (to avoid repeatitive use of $_POST). Which is not constructive as there is no one correct answer/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To organise data in such forms, you can use HTML form arrays. Assume we submitting huge amount of data about some house. I'd split data into sections for example: `general`, `geo`, `features`, `descriptions` and compose form like this.

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>General information</legend>
    <input type="number" name="general[pax]"  value="" placeholder="Pax"  />
    <input type="number" name="general[pets]" value="" placeholder="Pets" />
    <input type="text"   name="general[type]" value="" placeholder="Type" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>GEO data</legend>
    <input type="text" name="geo[longitude]" value="" placeholder="Longitude" />
    <input type="text" name="geo[latitude]"  value="" placeholder="Latitude" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Features</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="features[internet]" value="1" title="Internet" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="features[pool]" value="1" title="Pool" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="features[conditioner]" value="1" title="A/C" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:** using `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` tags and a bit of `jQuery` (*not demonstrated*) you can easily show/hide different groups and name them at your taste.

After submitting such form you will be able to access values like:

```php
$pets = (int)$_POST['general']['pets'];
$features = $_POST['features'];

$lon = (float)$_POST['geo']['longitude'];
$lat = (float)$_POST['geo']['latitude'];
```

It will ease your development and reduce efforts to control/parse/enumerate different groups of data.

**UPDATE:** or one more possible variant is

```html
<input type="text" name="params[param1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="params[param2]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="params[param3]" value="" />
```

meanwhile in `PHP`

```php
$params = $_POST['params']; // getting our isolated array of parameters
$names = array_keys($params); // extracting names from array
$values = array_values($params); // extracting values from array

$mysql->insert($names, $values) // and trying to implement desired solution
```

Comment: Yes, I do like it too, but when I open my php script and write smth such as : $varA = $_POST['param1]....$varZ = $_POST['param1000'] I depressed.

Comment: @d7p4x, I've updated my answer with `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` tags to be able to organize data groups in a form.

Comment: I don't think that <fieldset> required, I use simply name="program[1]"..name="program[10]" and it works =) but it's not comfortable. I want smth: $params[][] = $_POST['params']; $mysql-> insert($params['names'], $params['values']) is it reall? =)

Comment: @d7p4x Glad it helped ! Could you please mark question as `accepted`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14630/discussion-between-d7p4x-and-paul-t-rawkeen)

Answer (score 4):

I would split the information into sections and only display/ask a subset per section. Each section has a save/next button, and the data is saved on each section submit.